# iOS 8 Free Memory after WebView (swift)

Tags: ios, webview, swift

Currently i got a small problem with WebViews that dont release there memory usage in time, i m calling some webviews (the user can open them switch back to a map (via Tabbar) and open a new one),

Everytime a WebView is called it use up to 30MB RAM, so after 10 WebViews the App runs into a memory warning, so i m looking for a way (as i found in other Posts there is no way caus it handled automatic) to release the memory after switching back to the map from the webview.

This is how i call my WebView

```
import UIKit

class ViewController_webView: UIViewController {
/* ################################################## IBOutlets ################################################## */
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var TBB_shop: UITabBarItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!
/* ################################################## Home Button ################################################## */
    @IBAction func BThome(sender: AnyObject) {

        var shopurl = "http://google.com"
        let webviewURL = NSURL(string: shopurl)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: webviewURL)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
/* ################################################## ViewDidLoad ################################################## */
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var TBB_shop_img = UIImage(named: "TabbarShopping.png") as  UIImage
        TBB_shop.selectedImage = TBB_shop_img
    }
/* ################################################## MemoryWarning ################################################## */
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        println("Memory Warning")
    }
/* ################################################## viewWillAppear ################################################## */
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        var shopurl = "http://google.com"
        let webviewURL = NSURL(string: shopurl)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: webviewURL)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
/* ################################################## Activity Indicator ################################################## */
    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ : UIWebView){activity.startAnimating()}
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ : UIWebView){activity.stopAnimating()}



}
```

Is there anyway to use the

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        <#code#>
    }
```

to release the memory usage of a webview? Or anyway to reduce the usage of memory?

Answer (score 0):

From your code I deduce that the webView is in a nib.

To reduce the memory footprint, you might want to try creating and removing the webView in viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear, respectively.

This would mean that you might have to re-load the content if the user were to go back to it. Annoying from the user perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Releasing memory can depend on how you are bringing up the view - here is a modal presentation of a view controller - this will not release memory of a previously loaded view controller:

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WebViewController") as WebViewController       
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)!  
self.presentViewController( navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Below is a case where the rootViewController is replaced with the new controller - in this case the rootViewController value is changed - so the original view controller (if one was loaded before) reference count goes down to 0 and should be removed from memory, in theory:

```
 let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WebViewController") as WebViewController 
 let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)!     
 let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[0] as UIWindow
 window.rootViewController = navigationController
```

I tried the latter case in a code situation like what is described in the question.  I saw an improvement in memory releasing, however I have to admit that the memory did not go back where I started from - don't know why.  I hope somebody has a better solution.